# Spark - Write a DF with Struct Schema as CSV

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame that I created by reading an EBCDIC data file. Its schema is as follows

```
scala> myDF.printSchema
root
 |-- DF_RECORD: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- BALANCE_AMT: decimal(15,4) (nullable = true)
```

I can even get it to show its rows. But when I try to write it as CSV, I get the following error

```
scala> myDF.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save("/path")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support struct<ID:string,BALANCE_AMT:decimal(15,4)> data type.;
```

Is there a column conversion I might have to de before writing?

Spark version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

Scala version 2.11.12

Comment: yes, you have to convert that type to two columns, or maybe to an ArrayType(StringType) or a MapType(StringType, DecimalType)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `selectExpr` before writing

```
scala> myDF.selectExpr("DF_RECORD.*").write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save("/path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to individual columns by accessing columns names in `withColumn`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, Row, DoubleType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = StructType([
    StructField("DF_RECORD", 
      StructType([
          StructField("ID", StringType()),
          StructField("BALANCE_AMT", DoubleType())
      ])
      )
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(Row("1",1000.0))], schema=schema)
df.printSchema()

[Out]:
root
 |-- DF_RECORD: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- BALANCE_AMT: double (nullable = true)


df_csv = df \
          .withColumn("ID", F.col("DF_RECORD")["ID"]) \
          .withColumn("BALANCE_AMT", F.col("DF_RECORD")["BALANCE_AMT"]) \
          .drop("DF_RECORD")

[Out]:
+---+-----------+
| ID|BALANCE_AMT|
+---+-----------+
|  1|     1000.0|
+---+-----------+
```

Now, export it as CSV:

```py
df_csv.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save("/content/sample_data/test1.csv")

!cat "/content/sample_data/test1.csv/part-00000-b342e07a-6d41-40b5-afa2-39eeef3b70a2-c000.csv"

[Out]:
ID, BALANCE_AMT
1, 1000.0
```